# чтение COM через cmd

Tags: cmd, bat, com-порт

Облазив просторы форумов, пытался считать значения с COM порта через командную строку. Путём команды

```
type com11
```

как все советовали. Но в ответ ругается, мол "Не удаётся найти указанный файл". Может кто сталкивался? Либо батник может есть у кого?

Comment: По моему там с двузначными портами напрямую не работает и нужен какой-то хитрый способ. Попробую найти.

Comment: Вроде бы для двузначных портов нужно писать полный адрес \\.\COM11 то есть нужно писать type \\.\COM11